# treeSort statically with Object datas with array

Tags: java

I need to do a treeSort() I have the other methods for BST I need to the treeSort() and helper method

```
public static Object[] treeSort(Object[] data)
{
    return data;
}

//Helper method will follow after treeSort()
//helper method has to be IN ORDER traversal
```

It will be really helpful if someone would explain the algorithm, I get that in order to make this work I have to go the all the leaf node starting from the most left and then work on up to the root and then do the right side, however, I am having trouble with this. Yes, this is an assignment I do not need the code (would be helpful though) just more or less need the algorithm. BTW this is in java

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is an algorithm for building a sorted tree at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort Perhaps try implementing that and then come back if you have issues

Comment: To perform in order traversal, start with the root node and recursively read all the root.left nodes and push them into a stack.
Once you reach the leaf node, pop the stack, print it (or add to list, whatever) and then set root = root.right and continue recursively.

Here when you pop the stack and continue recursively, if root.right is null, you wud continue to pop the next element from stack, else if root.right is not null, consider it to be the root and again continue recursively to add root.left elements to stack.